# Equation Simplification

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any idea how to simplify this equation? Criteria for each region (APAC, LATAM, EMEA, North America) varies (hour/day cut offs).

Believe it or not, this used to be longer. Here is my best attempt:

Broken out by groupings:

```
=IF(A2="","",

IF(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=6,"Weekend Case",

IF(AND(C2<>"APAC",WEEKDAY(B2,2)=7),"WeekendCase", 

IF(AND(C2="APAC",OR(AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=5,HOUR(B2)>=3),AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=7,
HOUR(B2)<18))),"Weekend Case",

IF(AND(C2="North America",OR(AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=5,HOUR(B2)>=18),
AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=1,HOUR(B2)<8))),"Weekend Case",

IF(AND(C2="EMEA",OR(AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=5,HOUR(B2)>=10),
AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=1,HOUR(B2)<2))),"Weekend Case",

IF(AND(C2="LATAM",OR(AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=5,HOUR(B2)>=15),
AND(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=1,HOUR(B2)<5))),"Weekend Case",

"Weekday")))))))
```

---

Logic:

IF A2 = `Nothing`: `Nothing`

All Regions:
If `Sat`: `WEEKEND`

North America, EMEA, LATAM
IF `Sun`: `WEEKEND`

APAC:
IF `Friday After 3AM` OR `Sunday Before 6PM`: `WEEKEND`

North America:
IF `Friday After 6PM` OR `Monday Before 8AM`: `WEEKEND`

EMEA:
IF `Friday After 10AM` or `Monday Before 2AM`: `WEEKEND`

LATAM:
IF `Friday After 3PM` OR `Monday Before 5AM`: `WEEKEND`

Else:
 `WEEKDAY`

---

Sample for each region with each output below:

[image]

Comment: It would make it easier if you could describe precisely what the formula is trying to achieve.

Comment: It would be easier if you set up a reference table in another sheet defining start and stop times for weekends for each region. Your formula could do an easy search for region and then check the timestamp.

Comment: I don't think your formulas match your sample image data.

Comment: Which line does not follow the logic? Noticed a error on EMEA that I updated

Comment: Yeah, EMEA.  I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use an external table for Lookups, you  should be able to simplify it (and make it easier to change should the need arise)

Lookup table:

[image]

The numbers are the number of days to offset for the Monday (`col I`) and the Friday (`col J`). i.e. for APAC, + 6 hours is `=6/24` days and +21 hours is `=21/24` days. (Make sure to use formulas for this table and not the numbers that appear as those are rounded)

You can then use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(B2+VLOOKUP(C2,H$2:J$5,2))>=1,WEEKDAY(B2+VLOOKUP(C2,H$2:J$5,3))<=5),"Weekday","Weekend Case")
```

I get the same results with it as your sample.

Comment: I like the way you simplified the math needed for weekday comparison.  The only things I'd change are the reference table values.  I'd make the offset the hour amount itself and do the division (`x/24`) in the formula.  It makes the reference table visually cleaner and a little more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a reference sheet called Schedule, and load it as follows:

```
     A            B        C
1 Region       WE-start  WE-end
2 APAC           503      718
3 EMEA           505      802
4 LATAM          515      805
5 North America  518      818
```

The format of the WE values are `dhh` where d=weekday and hh=hour.  If weekday is a Sunday, I force it to an 8 to make the calculation that follows easier.

The following formula generates your Type and corrects the EMEA one.

```
=IF(AND(IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=1,700,0)+WEEKDAY(B2)*100+HOUR(B2)>=VLOOKUP(C2,Schedule!$A$2:$C$5,2), IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=1,700,0)+WEEKDAY(B2)*100+HOUR(B2)<VLOOKUP(C2,Schedule!$A$2:$C$5,3)),"Weekend Case","Weekday")
```